# Singleton pattern in PHP seems to not work

Tags: php, wordpress, singleton, wordpress-plugin-creation

My singleton pattern instance seems to lose its instance and becomes null between each request.

Whenever I call validate_api_endpoint_field when the settings are saved, my breakpoint is hit inside in the MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance() and its value is null.

any tips?

**MyPlugin_Settings.php**

```php
<?php

defined('ABSPATH') || exit;

if (!class_exists('MyPlugin_Settings')) {

    class MyPlugin_Settings
    {
        const page = "myPlugin-settings";
        const option_group_name = 'myPlugin_option_group';
        const domain = "myPlugin";
        protected static $_instance = null;

        public function __construct()
        {
            self::load_dependencies();
        }

        public function load_dependencies()
        {
            require_once PAYDAY_PATH . 'classes/class-myPlugin-repository.php';
            require_once PAYDAY_PATH . 'classes/class-myPlugin-request-manager.php';
        }

        public static function instance()
        {
            if (is_null(self::$_instance)) {
                self::$_instance = new self();
            }
            return self::$_instance;
        }

        public function admin_menu()
        {
            // Add a separator before the menu item.
            // Bug: Makes the WooCommerce Product menu disappear
            // slef::add_admin_menu_separator( 26 );
            add_menu_page(
                'MyPlugin',
                'MyPlugin',
                'manage_options',
                'myPlugin-settings',
                null,
                'dashicons-building',
                27
            );

            add_submenu_page('myPlugin', 'MyPlugin Settings', 'Settings', 'manage_options', self::page, array($this, 'render_plugin_settings'));

            // TODO: Uncomment when Dashboard will be implemented
            // add_submenu_page( 'myPlugin', 'Dashboard', 'Dashboard', 'manage_options', 'myPlugin', array(
            // $this,
            // 'display_page'
            // ) );
        }

        function add_admin_menu_separator($position)
        {
            global $menu;
            $index = 0;
            foreach ($menu as $offset => $section) {
                if (substr($section[2], 0, 9) == 'separator') {
                    $index++;
                }
                if ($offset >= $position) {
                    $menu[$position] = array('', 'read', "separator{$index}", '', 'wp-menu-separator');
                    break;
                }
            }
            ksort($menu);
        }

        public function admin_init()
        {
            self::register_api_settings();
            self::register_payment_methods_mapping();
            self::register_payment_methods_create_invoice_on_order_status_mapping();
            self::register_additional_invoice_settings_section();
        }

        public function admin_footer_text()
        {
            $current_screen = get_current_screen();
            $base = $current_screen->parent_base;
            if (substr($base, 0, 6) === "myPlugin") {
                echo '<span id="footer-thankyou">' . esc_html__('Developed by MyPlugin ehf.', 'myPlugin') . '</span>';
            }
        }

        public function register_api_settings()
        {
            $settings_section_id = 'myPlugin_api_section';
            add_settings_section(
                $settings_section_id,
                esc_html__('API Settings', 'myPlugin'),
                function () {
                    echo '<p>' . esc_html__('Access your ClientId and ClientSecret on MyPlugin.is underneath Settings -> Company Settings -> API', 'myPlugin') . '</p>';
                },
                self::page
            );

            // ClientId
            $client_id_settings_field_id = "myPlugin_client_id";
            add_settings_field(
                $client_id_settings_field_id,
                esc_html__('ClientID', 'myPlugin'),
                array($this, 'display_field'),
                self::page,
                $settings_section_id,
                array(
                    'type' => 'text', // Type of input field
                    'id' => $client_id_settings_field_id,
                    'class' => 'input-lg',
                    'name' => 'myPlugin_client_id',
                    'value' => get_option($client_id_settings_field_id, '') // The current value of the field, or set default value
                )
            );
            register_setting(self::option_group_name, $client_id_settings_field_id, array($this, 'validate_clientId_field'));

            // ClientSecret
            $client_secret_settings_field_id = "myPlugin_client_secret";
            add_settings_field(
                $client_secret_settings_field_id,
                esc_html__('ClientSecret', 'myPlugin'),
                array($this, 'display_field'),
                self::page,
                $settings_section_id,
                array(
                    'type' => 'password', // Type of input field
                    'id' => $client_secret_settings_field_id,
                    'class' => 'input-lg',
                    'name' => 'myPlugin_client_secret',
                    'value' => get_option($client_secret_settings_field_id, '') // The current value of the field, or set default value
                )
            );
            register_setting(self::option_group_name, $client_secret_settings_field_id, array($this, 'validate_clientSecret_field'));

            // API Endpoint
            $api_endpoint_field_id = 'myPlugin_api_endpoint';
            add_settings_field(
                $api_endpoint_field_id,
                esc_html__('API Endpoint', 'myPlugin'),
                array($this, 'display_select_field'),
                self::page,
                $settings_section_id,
                array(
                    'name' => 'myPlugin_api_endpoint',
                    'options' => [
                        esc_html__("Production", 'myPlugin') => "https://api.myPlugin.is",
                        esc_html__("Test", 'myPlugin') => "https://api.test.myPlugin.is",
                        esc_html__("Localhost", 'myPlugin') => "http://localhost:57283"
                    ]
                )
            );
            register_setting(self::option_group_name, $api_endpoint_field_id, array($this, 'validate_api_endpoint_field'));
        }

        public function register_payment_methods_mapping()
        {
            $settings_section_id = 'myPlugin_payment_methods_mapping_section';
            add_settings_section(
                $settings_section_id, // ID used to identify this section and with which to register options
                // Title to be displayed on the administration page
                __("Payment Methods - Mapping", 'myPlugin'),
                // Callback used to render the description of the section
                function () {
                    // TODO: Update if needed for redirecting for creating a new Payment Type within MyPlugin
                    echo '<p>' . __('Make sure the WooCommerce payment methods corresponds to the correct MyPlugin payment type.', 'myPlugin') . '</p>';
                    echo '<p>' . __('You might need to create a new payment type in MyPlugin first.', 'myPlugin') . '</p>';
                },
                // The page where to display the section
                self::page
            );

            //$woocommerce_payment_methods = WC_Payment_Gateways::instance()->get_available_payment_gateways();
            $woocommerce_payment_methods = WC_Payment_Gateways::instance()->payment_gateways();
            $myPlugin_payment_types = MyPlugin_Repository::instance()->get_payment_types();
            if (!isset($myPlugin_payment_types)) {
                $myPlugin_payment_types = MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance()->get_sales_payment_types();
                MyPlugin_Repository::instance()->set_payment_types($myPlugin_payment_types);
            }

            $payment_type_select_options = array();
            $payment_type_select_options[__('None', 'myPlugin')] = 'None';
            if (isset($myPlugin_payment_types)) {
                foreach ($myPlugin_payment_types as &$payment_type) {
                    // key => value
                    if (isset($payment_type) and gettype($payment_type) === "object") {
                        $payment_type = get_object_vars($payment_type);
                        $payment_type_select_options[$payment_type['title']] = $payment_type['id'];
                    }
                    if (isset($payment_type) and gettype($payment_type) === "array") {
                        $payment_type_select_options[$payment_type['title']] = $payment_type['id'];
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach ($woocommerce_payment_methods as $payment_method) {
                if ($payment_method->enabled == 'no') {
                    continue;
                }
                $id = $payment_method->id;

                $title = $payment_method->get_method_title();
                if ($title == "") {
                    try {
                        $title = $payment_method->title;
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $title = "";
                    }
                }
                $field_id = 'myPlugin_payment_method_' . $id;

                add_settings_field(
                    $field_id,
                    esc_html__($title, 'myPlugin'),
                    array($this, 'display_select_field'),
                    self::page,
                    $settings_section_id,
                    array(
                        'name' => esc_html__($field_id, 'myPlugin'),
                        'options' => $payment_type_select_options
                    )
                );

                register_setting(self::option_group_name, $field_id);
            }
        }

        public function register_payment_methods_create_invoice_on_order_status_mapping()
        {
            $settings_section_id = 'myPlugin_create_invoice_on_order_status_section';
            add_settings_section(
                $settings_section_id,
                'Payment Methods - Action: Create an invoice and mark it as paid',
                function () {
                    echo '<p>' . esc_html__('Please select the corresponding WooCommerce Order Status to execute the following action:', 'myPlugin') . '</p>';
                    echo '<p>' . esc_html__('Create a new invoice in MyPlugin and mark it as paid.', 'myPlugin') . '</p>';
                },
                self::page
            );
            $woocommerce_payment_methods = WC_Payment_Gateways::instance()->payment_gateways();

            foreach ($woocommerce_payment_methods as $payment_method) {
                if ($payment_method->enabled == 'no') {
                    continue;
                }
                $id = $payment_method->id;
                $title = $payment_method->get_method_title();
                if ($title == "") {
                    try {
                        $title = $payment_method->title;
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $title = "";
                    }
                }

                $field_id = 'myPlugin_payment_method_' . $id . '_create_invoice_on_action';
                $order_statuses = wc_get_order_statuses();


                add_settings_field(
                    $field_id,
                    esc_html__($title, 'myPlugin'),
                    array($this, 'display_select_field'),
                    self::page,
                    $settings_section_id,
                    array(
                        'name' => $field_id,
                        'options' => [
                            __("None", 'myPlugin') => "None",
                            __($order_statuses["wc-processing"], 'myPlugin') => "processing",
                            __($order_statuses["wc-completed"], 'myPlugin') => "completed",
                        ]
                    )
                );

                register_setting(self::option_group_name, $field_id);
            }
        }

        public function register_additional_invoice_settings_section()
        {
            $settings_section_id = 'myPlugin_invoice_settings_section';
            add_settings_section(
                $settings_section_id,
                'Invoice Settings',
                function () {
                },
                self::page
            );

            $send_email_on_invoice_create_field_id = "myPlugin_send_email_on_invoice_create";
            add_settings_field(
                $send_email_on_invoice_create_field_id,
                esc_html__("Email the invoice as a PDF to customer when created", "myPlugin"),
                array($this, 'display_select_field'),
                self::page,
                $settings_section_id,
                array(
                    'name' => "myPlugin_send_email_on_invoice_create",
                    'options' => [
                        esc_html__('Yes', 'myPlugin') => "yes",
                        esc_html__('No', 'myPlugin') => "no",
                    ]
                )
            );

            register_setting(self::option_group_name, $send_email_on_invoice_create_field_id);

            $invoice_date_option = "myPlugin_invoice_date_option";
            add_settings_field(
                $invoice_date_option,
                esc_html__("When Invoice is created, invoice date and due date set to", "myPlugin"),
                array($this, 'display_select_field'),
                self::page,
                $settings_section_id,
                array(
                    'name' => "myPlugin_invoice_date_option",
                    'options' => [
                        esc_html__('to the date the order was first created', 'myPlugin') => "0",
                        esc_html__('to the date when the request is made to create an invoice', 'myPlugin') => "1",
                    ]
                )
            );

            register_setting(self::option_group_name, $invoice_date_option);
        }

        public function validate_clientId_field($input)
        {
            $valid = true;
            $value = $input;

            if (!isset($value) || empty(trim($value))) {
                // We must support empty string when we clear cache and set value to empty string
                return "";
                // $valid = false;
                // add_settings_error(
                //     'myPlugin_option_group',
                //     'myPlugin_clientId_error',
                //     esc_html__('ClientID is required.', 'myPlugin')
                // );
            }

            if ($valid) {
                $value = sanitize_text_field($value);
                $value = strtolower($value);
            }

            if ($valid) {
                if (strlen($value) != 32) {
                    $valid = false;
                    add_settings_error(
                        'myPlugin_option_group',
                        'myPlugin_clientId_error',
                        esc_html__('Invalid value for ClientID. Value has to be 32 characters long.', 'myPlugin')
                    );
                }
            }

            if ($valid) {
                if (!ctype_xdigit($value) || !self::is_valid_guid($value)) {
                    $valid = false;
                    add_settings_error(
                        'myPlugin_option_group',
                        'myPlugin_clientId_error',
                        esc_html__('Invalid value for ClientID. Value has to be a hexadecimal number.', 'myPlugin')
                    );
                }
            }

            // Ignore the user's changes and use the old database value.
            if (!$valid) {
                $value = get_option('myPlugin_client_id');
            }

            return $value;
        }

        public function validate_clientSecret_field($input)
        {
            $valid = true;
            $value = $input;

            if (!isset($value) || empty(trim($value))) {
                return "";
                // $valid = false;
                // add_settings_error(
                //     'myPlugin_option_group',
                //     'myPlugin_clientSecret_error',
                //     esc_html__('ClientSecret is required.', 'myPlugin')
                // );
            }

            if ($valid) {
                $value = trim($value);
                $value = sanitize_text_field($value);
                $value = strtolower($value);
            }

            if ($valid) {
                if (strlen($value) != 32) {
                    $valid = false;
                    add_settings_error(
                        'myPlugin_option_group',
                        'myPlugin_clientSecret_error',
                        esc_html__('Invalid value for ClientSecret. Value has to be 32 characters long.', 'myPlugin')
                    );
                }
            }

            if ($valid) {
                if (!ctype_xdigit($value) || !self::is_valid_guid($value)) {
                    $valid = false;
                    add_settings_error(
                        'myPlugin_option_group',
                        'myPlugin_clientSecret_error',
                        esc_html__('Invalid value for ClientSecret. Value has to be a hexadecimal number.', 'myPlugin')
                    );
                }
            }

            // Ignore the user's changes and use the old database value.
            if (!$valid) {
                $value = get_option('myPlugin_client_secret');
            }

            return $value;
        }

        // Last of three main credentials validation functions.
        // we will validate all three credentials at once if the values have changed. if it is valid we will save the new values to this instance.
        public function validate_api_endpoint_field($input)
        {
            $valid = true;
            $value = $input;

            $value = trim($value);
            if (!isset($value) || empty($value)) {
                return "";
                // $valid = false;
                // add_settings_error(
                //     'myPlugin_option_group',
                //     'myPlugin_api_endpoint_error',
                //     esc_html__('API Endpoint is required.', 'myPlugin')
                // );
            }

            $value = sanitize_text_field($value);

            if (!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
                $valid = false;
                add_settings_error(
                    'myPlugin_option_group',
                    'myPlugin_api_endpoint_error',
                    esc_html__('Invalid value for API Endpoint. Value has to be a valid URL.', 'myPlugin')
                );
            }

            if ($valid) {
                $credential_changed = false;
                $old_clientId = MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance()->get_client_id();
                $old_clientSecret =  MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance()->get_client_secret();
                $old_api_endpoint = MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance()->get_api_endpoint();

                $new_clientId = get_option('myPlugin_client_id');
                $new_clientSecret = get_option('myPlugin_client_secret');
                $new_api_endpoint = $value;

                if ($new_clientId != $old_clientId)
                    $credential_changed = true;
                if ($new_clientSecret != $old_clientSecret)
                    $credential_changed = true;
                if ($new_api_endpoint != $old_api_endpoint)
                    $credential_changed = true;

                if ($credential_changed) {
                    if(isset($new_clientId) && !empty(trim($new_clientId))  
                    && isset($new_clientSecret) && !empty(trim($new_clientSecret)) 
                    && isset($new_api_endpoint) &&! empty(trim($new_api_endpoint))) {
                        MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance()->set_client_id($new_clientId);
                        MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance()->set_client_secret($new_clientSecret);
                        MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance()->set_api_endpoint($new_api_endpoint);
                        $new_auth_token = MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance()->get_new_auth_token_and_save();
                        if (!isset($new_auth_token) || empty($new_auth_token)) {
                            $valid = false;
                            add_settings_error(
                                'myPlugin_option_group',
                                'myPlugin_api_endpoint_error',
                                esc_html__('Credentials are invalid. Please check your ClientID, ClientSecret and selected Api Endpoint. Make sure you have the correct values, and that you have saved the settings in MyPlugin.', 'myPlugin')
                            );
                        }
                    }else{
                        $valid = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Ignore the user's changes and use the old database value.
            if (!$valid) {
                // $value = get_option('myPlugin_api_endpoint');
                // MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance()->set_client_id(get_option('myPlugin_client_id'));
                // MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance()->set_client_secret(get_option('myPlugin_client_secret'));
                // MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance()->set_api_endpoint(get_option('myPlugin_api_endpoint'));
            } else {
                add_settings_error(
                    'myPlugin_option_group',
                    'myPlugin_api_endpoint_updated',
                    esc_html('Connection established.', 'myPlugin'),
                    'updated'
                );
            }

            return $value;
        }

        public function display_field($args)
        {
            if ($args['type'] == 'password') {
            }
            echo "<input class=" . esc_html($args['class']) . " id=" . esc_html($args['id']) . " name=" . esc_html($args['name']) . " type='" . esc_html($args['type']) . "' value='" . esc_html($args['value']) . "' />";
        }

        public function display_select_field($args)
        {
            print("<select name=" . $args['name'] . ">");
            foreach ($args['options'] as $key => $value) {
                print("<option value=" . esc_html($value) . (selected(get_option(esc_html($args['name'])), esc_html($value)) ? "  selected>" : ">") . esc_html__($key, 'myPlugin') . "</option>");
            }
            print("</select>");
        }

        public function plugin_action_links($links, $file)
        {
            if (substr($file, 0, 6) === "myPlugin") {
                $settings_link = "<a href=\"admin.php?page=" . self::page . "\">" . esc_html__('Settings', 'myPlugin') . "</a>";
                // Insert in front
                array_unshift($links, $settings_link);
            }

            return $links;
        }

        // Refresh Values button handler
        public function admin_post_myPlugin_settings_refresh()
        {
            if (isset($_POST['refresh'])) {
                $repository = MyPlugin_Repository::instance();
                $repository->delete_payment_types();
                $myPlugin_payment_types = MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance()->get_sales_payment_types();
                $repository->set_payment_types($myPlugin_payment_types);

                wp_safe_redirect(esc_url(admin_url('admin.php?page=' . self::page)));
            }
        }

        // Clear Cache button handler
        public function admin_post_myPlugin_settings_clear_cache()
        {
            if (isset($_POST['clear_cache'])) {
                $repository = MyPlugin_Repository::instance();
                $repository->delete_payment_types();
                $repository->delete_invoice_meta();
                $repository->delete_auth_tokens();


                $all_options = wp_load_alloptions();
                if (isset($all_options)) {
                    foreach ($all_options as $option_name => $option_value) {
                        if (substr($option_name, 0, 6) === "myPlugin") {
                            update_option($option_name, "");
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance()->set_client_id("");
                MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance()->set_client_secret("");
                MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance()->set_api_endpoint("");

                wp_safe_redirect(esc_url(admin_url('admin.php?page=' . self::page)));
            }
        }

        public function is_valid_guid($str)
        {
            return preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{12}[4][0-9a-f]{19}$/', $str);
        }

        public function render_plugin_settings()
        {
?>
            <div class="myPlugin_settings_wrap">
                <h1><?php echo esc_html__("Settings", 'myPlugin'); ?></h1>
                <div class="clear">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=checkout&section=myPlugin')); ?>">
                        <input type="button" class="button" value="<?php echo esc_html__('MyPlugin Claim Service Settings', 'myPlugin') ?>">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <?php 
                if(MyPlugin_Request_Manager::instance()->is_connected_to_endpoint()) {
                    echo "<h2 style='color:green;'>" . esc_html__("Active.", 'myPlugin') . "</h2>";
                }else{
                    echo "<h2 style='color:red;'>" . esc_html__("This plugin is not active. Please fill in your credentials and save.", 'myPlugin') . "</h2>";
                }
                ?>
                <form method="POST" action="options.php">
                    <?php
                    settings_errors('myPlugin_option_group');
                    // Allocate all fields for a option group
                    settings_fields('myPlugin_option_group');
                    // Displays all the sections that are assigned to a certain page
                    do_settings_sections('myPlugin-settings');
                    // Render a Save Change button
                    submit_button();
                    ?>
                </form>

                <!-- Inline Button Row - START -->
                <form method="POST" action="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?>" style="display: inline-block">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myPlugin_settings_refresh">
                    <input type="submit" id="refresh" name="refresh" class="button" value="<?php echo esc_html__("Refresh Values", 'myPlugin'); ?>">
                </form>

                <form method="POST" action="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?>" style="display: inline-block; padding-left: 5px;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myPlugin_settings_clear_cache">
                    <input type="submit" id="Disconnect" name="clear_cache" class="button" value="<?php echo esc_html__("Clear Cache", 'myPlugin'); ?>">
                </form>

            </div>
<?php
        }
    }
}
```

**MyPlugin_Request_Manager.php**

```php
<?php

defined('ABSPATH') || exit;

if (!class_exists('MyPlugin_Request_Manager')) {

    class MyPlugin_Request_Manager
    {
        // This is the singleton instance
        private static $_instance = null;

        protected $client_id;
        protected $client_secret;
        protected $api_endpoint;
        protected $token;
        protected $token_created_at;


        // The constructor is private
        // to prevent initiation with outer code.
        private function __construct()
        {
            // Use $this instead of static::$_instance
            $this->load_dependencies();
        }

        public function load_dependencies()
        {
            require_once MYPLUGIN_PATH . 'classes/class-myPlugin-repository.php';
            require_once MYPLUGIN_PATH . 'classes/class-myPlugin-utils.php';
        }

        public static function instance()
        {
            if (static::$_instance == null) {
                static::$_instance = new MyPlugin_Request_Manager();
                static::$_instance->set_client_id(get_option('myPlugin_client_id'));
                static::$_instance->set_client_secret(get_option('myPlugin_client_secret'));
                static::$_instance->set_api_endpoint(get_option('myPlugin_api_endpoint'));
            }
            return static::$_instance;
        }

        public function get_client_id()
        {
            return static::$_instance->client_id;
        }

        public function set_client_id(string $client_id)
        {
            static::$_instance->client_id = $client_id;
        }

        public function get_client_secret()
        {
            return static::$_instance->client_secret;
        }

        public function set_client_secret(string $client_secret)
        {
            static::$_instance->client_secret = $client_secret;
        }

        public function get_api_endpoint()
        {
            return static::$_instance->api_endpoint;
        }

        public function set_api_endpoint(string $api_endpoint)
        {
            static::$_instance->api_endpoint = $api_endpoint;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the singleton instance created one time per request, or every time you call the ::instance() method? An instance will need to be created once per request, `static` does not mean that the property persists outside of the the request lifecycle.

Comment: It is created per request not every time I call the ::instance(). Any solution on how to make it persist between request lifecycles?

Comment: No, that's not possible in PHP. You could serialize and store the object (file, Memcache, Redis, etc), then fetch and unserialize when you need it. There's no way to have it living in memory somewhere and shared across requests like you would in a Java servlet container or something.

Comment: By its default nature, the web is stateless.  Each user is using it's own instance of the application and it's variables.  You can persist some things between requests from the same user using sessions and cookies.  But to do it across users requires a more persistent storage such as a database or a file.  The question is, why are you trying to persist it?